# How to keep Nil from reverting container to its default value?

Tags: data-structures, nodes, raku

I'm implementing a simple linked list and to denote the fact that there is no next node, I'm using the value `Nil`. The thing is that when assigned to a container, `Nil` will attempt to revert the container to its default value which means I need to use the container's default value or `Any` to determine if the linked list's end has been reached. However, I'd still like to use `Nil` (if only for its clear intent) and no other value to test for the non-existence of a next node in the code (e.g., `until $current === Any`, `last if $current-node === Any;`). For some context:

```
class Node {
    has $.data is rw is required;
    has $.next is rw = Nil;
}

class UnorderedList {
    has $!head = Nil;
    
    method add(\item --> Nil) {
        my $temp = Node.new: data => item;
        $temp.next = $!head;
        $!head = $temp;
    }

    method size(--> UInt) {
        my $current = $!head;
        my UInt $count = 0;
        
        until $current === Any {          # <=== HERE
            $count += 1;
            $current .= next;
        }
        
        return $count;
    }
   
    method gist(--> Str) {
        my $current-node = $!head;
        my $items := gather loop {
            last if $current-node === Any; # <=== HERE
            take $current-node.data;
            $current-node .= next;
        }
        
        $items.join(', ')
    }
}
```

Comment: Before attempting to understand the problem or answer, wouldn't it be a better idea to create a "None" value totally unrelated to Nil with its own semantics?

Comment: Again, not trying to answer, but [`IterationEnd`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterator#index-entry-IterationEnd) is also intended for that purpose. Still haven't got into your problem, but it might be that using Nil is precisely the problem.

Comment: `IterationEnd` is really an implementation detail that is only documented to help developers of classes that implement the `Iterator` role.  It should *not* be used anywhere else, as it can create unexpected effects, especially as soon as such a value is produced by an Iterator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bit like asking "how can I still have rain fall on my head while using an umbrella". :-) The primary reason `Nil` exists in Raku is to provide a value that a function can return on a soft failure to produce a result, which will be safe if assigned into any container that supports being undefined (or defaulted).

Thus, one can write a function `func` that can return `Nil`, and it will Just Work for a caller `my SomeType $foo = func()` or for a caller `my OtherType $bar = func()`.

While there is the `is default(Nil)` trick, I'd strongly suggest using some other value as your sentinel. Trying to use a language feature in a situation where you don't want the primary behavior it exists to provide will generally not go smoothly.

The `Node` type object itself would be a reasonable choice. Thus this:

```
has $!head = Nil;
```

Becomes:

```
has Node $!head;
```

And the test becomes:

```
until $current === Node {
```

However, I'd probably write it as:

```
while $current.defined {
```

Which also supports subclassing of `Node`. On the other hand, if I know `Node` is an implementation detail of my class, I'd feel safe enough to use rely on the default boolification semantics to remove the clutter:

```
while $current {
```

Meanwhile, this:

```
last if $current-node === Any;
```

Could become:

```
last without $current-node;
```

Or for consistency if choosing the "rely on the boolification" approach:

```
last unless $current-node;
```

Finally, if `Node` is just an implementation detail, I'd move it inside `UnorderedList` and make it `my` scoped.

Answer (score 8):

Some choices, with the ones I would find most appealing toward the top, and one I would positively discourage at the bottom:

- Use `Node` (the type object of your `Node` class).  *This is the option jnthn recommends.* This would make sense to all rakuns familiar with Raku's distinction between defined and undefined values, and would be especially convenient if you add `Node` type constraints to node variables. Imo this would be the idiomatic solution.
- Use [`Empty`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/Empty). It arguably has most of the same positives as `Nil` without most of the negatives I perceive and discuss later in this answer. If you go with `Empty` (or `End` or whatever) you can create a `subset MaybeNode where Node | Empty` or whatever to allow for adding a type constraint to a node variable. (Though such boilerplate mostly serves just to highlight the simple elegant ergonomics that underly the option of using `Node`.)
- Use `is default(Nil)` to set the default for the node attribute.  *This is the option Liz suggested.* Again, one can use, say, `is default(Empty)` as part of using anything other than `Node`.
- Pick a new name. `None` might be a poor choice because it has an established meaning in many languages that has yet other semantics. Perhaps `End`? (Declared as, say, `role End {}`.)
- Declare your own `Nil` and lexically shadow Raku's built in `Nil`. I would say that that's a crazy thing to do; and would remonstrate against it if I were to peer review your code; and would anticipate most rakuns agreeing with me; but you *could*.

## Further discussion of the options

Per [`Nil`'s doc](https://docs.raku.org/type/Nil), its definition is:

> Absence of a value **or a benign failure**

Imo this overloading is genius on Larry's part. But it is best respected for what it is. It's not just an overloaded semantic but *explicitly* so. Continuing with the doc:

> `Failure` is derived from `Nil`, so smartmatching `Nil` will also match `Failure`. ... Along with `Failure`, `Nil` and its subclasses may always be returned from a routine even when the routine specifies a particular return type [even] regardless of the definedness of the return type.

*All* of these semantics will mentally and actually apply to your code even if you don't want them. Are you *absolutely sure* you want them? See my first reply to @ElizabethMattijsen in comments below this answer for a brief discussion of the sort of troubles I'm suggesting this can lead to. And another is that folk *reading* your code could *think* of the same troubles. This is arguably an unnecessary overhead.

On the other hand, such troubles (actual rather than imagined) are pretty unlikely even in fairly complicated code. And your code is very simple. So my focus on this failure aspect is overblown for your provided scenario. And Liz's solution is simple and nice.

On the gripping hand, it's also nice to adopt simple solutions that are most generally applicable, even for the most complex code, and to expose newbies to those simple and general solutions early on. Also it's possible that you were interested in hearing about the range of options. And of course I might be wrong about what I write and get good feedback. Hence this answer.

> I'd still like to use `Nil` (if only for its clear intent)

If the code is only for your eyes, then whatever you find clear is for you to decide.

Imo the clear intent of `Nil` to those who know Raku is to symbolize Raku's `Nil`.

Raku's `Nil` has the specific semantics I quoted above.

To the degree someone focuses their attention on "absence of a value", your solution will seem perfectly cromulent. To the degree they focus on "benign failure", and consider how this semantic is used throughout Raku, they may raise an eyebrow. Clearly, reaching the node that has no next node fits pretty well with "benign failure" as well as "absence of value". Indeed, this is why Larry overloaded them. But *other code* is also using `Nil` to mean these things, and they probably don't mean "end of link list".

A similar mixed story applies to `Node` and `Empty`, but with different flavors.

`Node` makes a lot of sense because it's idiomatic in Raku that a type object is undefined, and you can type constrain a node variable and it'll accept `Node`. But it's also an idiomatic way to represent something being uninitialized. Do you really want that overloaded semantic? Maybe it's fine, maybe it's not.

`Empty` makes sense because it reads well, is undefined like `Nil` and `Node` (but without their other unwanted semantics), and the chances of encountering it by mistake are vanishingly small. Its downsides are that it misses the nice idiomatic duality of `Node` for defined / undefined values; it's not quite as ultra safe as a new locally defined name (eg `End`); someone might wonder why your code is using a `Slip`; and it's by definition not going to be quite as appealing to you as `Nil` given your stated preference.

Comment: I think "test for the non-existence of a next node in the code" matches "explicitly indicate that no value is present", and that therefore `Nil` and `is default(Nil)` are a valid way of approaching this.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I'm not saying it's not a valid approach. Raku's built in `Nil` explicitly indicates no value is present **or benign failure**. Any code that fails is free to return `Nil` to indicate it went wrong in a manner it wishes to indicate is benign. But it may not be benign. If, when writing linked list code, one is confident it will never evolve in its lifetime to encounter some code that has a benign failure (or a bug that manifests as if it were a benign failure) in such a way that that gets written as the link value then sure. But imo the idiomatic solution would be `Node`.

Comment: hi @raiph - great, comprehensive answer (as usual), it did send me searching for the ```Node``` type on rakudocs, until I realised you mean the type object of the class that uxlzzzz defined - so suggest a short edit to your answer to explicitly state that (?)

Comment: @p6steve Oops. Fixed. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:  `Nil` can *also* be a default value.  So instead of saying:

```
has $.next is rw = Nil;
```

all you have to do, is:

```
has $.next is rw is default(Nil);
```

Assigning `Nil` to such an rw attribute, will give you `Nil`.

Comment: A pretty straightforward solution! However, the issue I encountered is that I must declare with `is default(Nil)` any variable that stores `$!head` and that will subsequently be "iterated over" (e.g., `$current-node`) if I wanted to keep using the value identity comparison. Using raiph's first point does the trick a little bit cleaner while also making the intent clear ((defined vs undefined). Although to be honest, using the value identity operator (`===`) was a bit of an overkill and relying on Raku's defined and undefined values would've done the job too.

Comment: I was going for your comment "However, I'd still like to use Nil (if only for its clear intent)", and gave you the answer to that.  But indeed, TIMTOWTDI  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! TIMTOWTDI indeed :-)!