# In Raku, what is the "Node" type or distinguished value?

Tags: types, tree, raku

I've been unable to find any description or documentation using web and Raku doc search. But Node is referenced as a type in the top answer to the question [How to keep Nil from reverting container to its default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742323/how-to-keep-nil-from-reverting-container-to-its-default-value) and based on the description in that answer, the Node type / value would be useful to me.

Note that this has **nothing to do with Node.js**! (Except that I get a lot of irrelevant search results.)

Comment: The node class is declared in the code example posted in the question linked to.

Comment: Hi @jedharris. Is p6steve's comment above enough of an explanation? If so the norm for SO would be that either you delete your question or we close it. If instead you'd like more of an explanation, please let us know either by editing your question to talk more about what you're after, or just adding a comment below mine to say you'd still like an answer to your question as it stands. TIA, and sorry about the confusion.

Comment: p6steve's answer is excellent. The key is the idea of using the type object as the undefined instance which indeed is elegant. The answers to the linked question weren't explicit enough to make that connection for me, even though I did know that type objects are undefined instances. p6steve should get credit for an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on the same page as you - this answer sent me to search for 'Node' in the raku docs. Then I gathered that the 'Node' in question is the class defined in the original question. Any raku class can be instantiated as a type object (docs.raku.org/language/classtut#index-entry-type_object ) or as an instance object. The way I think about this is that the type object is an empty ("undefined") instance that can still access any class variables. So it's a perfect, type consistent, candidate for an 'empty' sentinel for this example...